# I keep getting error when trying to run a python GUI radio button program.

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter

This is the error i get.

Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\kl_nnanna\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\tkinter__init__.py", line 1550, in **call**
    return self.func(*args)
  File "C:/Users/kl_nnanna/PycharmProjects/future_value/Idcalls.py", line 71, in calc_price
    radio = self.radio_var.get()
  File "C:\Users\kl_nnanna\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\tkinter__init__.py", line 355, in get
    return self._tk.getint(self._tk.globalgetvar(self._name))
TypeError: getint() argument must be str, not float

This is my code.

import tkinter
import tkinter.messagebox

class LongCallsGUI:
    def **init**(self):
        # Create main window.
        self.main_window = tkinter.Tk()

```
    # Create frames for the radio button and for button widgets.
    self.top_frame = tkinter.Frame(self.main_window)
    self.minute_frame = tkinter.Frame(self.main_window)
    self.bottom_frame = tkinter.Frame(self.main_window)

    # Create an IntVar object to use the radio buttons.
    self.radio_var = tkinter.IntVar()

    # Set the IntVar to 1.
    self.radio_var.set(1)

    # Create the RadioButton widgets in the top frame.
    self.rb1 = tkinter.Radiobutton(self.top_frame, \
                                   text ='Daytime: $0.07', variable=self.radio_var,\
                                   value= 0.07)
    self.rb2 = tkinter.Radiobutton(self.top_frame, \
                                   text ='Evening: $0.12', variable=self.radio_var,\
                                   value= 0.12)
    self.rb3 = tkinter.Radiobutton(self.top_frame, \
                                   text ='Off-Peak: $0.05', variable=self.radio_var,\
                                   value= 0.05)

    # Pack the RadioButtons
    self.rb1.pack()
    self.rb2.pack()
    self.rb3.pack()

    # Create and pack the widgets for minutes.
    self.minute_label = tkinter.Label(self.minute_frame, \
                                      text='Enter the minutes of call:')
    self.minute_entry = tkinter.Entry(self.minute_frame, \
                                      width=10)
    self.minute_label.pack(side='left')
    self.minute_entry.pack(side='left')

    # Create an OK button and Quit button.
    self.calc_button = tkinter.Button(self.bottom_frame, \
                                    text='Price', command=self.calc_price)
    self.quit_button = tkinter.Button(self.bottom_frame, \
                                      text='Quit', command=self.main_window.destroy)

    # Pack the buttons.
    self.calc_button.pack(side='left')
    self.quit_button.pack(side='left')

    # Pack the frames.
    self.top_frame.pack()
    self.minute_frame.pack()
    self.bottom_frame.pack()

    # Start the mainloop
    tkinter.mainloop()

def calc_price(self):
    # Get the value entered by user.
    radio = self.radio_var.get()
    minute = float(self.minute_entry.get())

    price = radio * minute

    tkinter.messagebox.showinfo('Price', 'You total is' + str(self.radio_var.get()) +\
                                str(price))
```

## Create an instance of the LongCallsGUI class.

my_gui = LongCallsGUI()

Comment: you need to fix the formatting of your question. Also, if you're wanting to store floating point values, why are you using an `IntVar`?

Comment: @BryanOakley it is my first question, so did not really know how to format it. But will do better next time. Thank you.

Comment: edit question and use button `{}` to format code and error message.